# Deleting all records apart from one, and only with a field value in 'type'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Script that runs in php - what it does is when a user logs in, it deletes all old tokens except from the latest 3.

```
    DELETE tokens FROM tokens
    LEFT JOIN (    
    SELECT id
    FROM tokens
    WHERE users_id = :user_id
    ORDER BY access_time DESC
    LIMIT 3) AS newest
    ON tokens.id = newest.id
    WHERE tokens.users_id = :user_id AND newest.id IS NULL
```

This works perfectly, however i tried to modify it so that this only works for all of the tokens that have a type set to either "API" or to "APP"

So in theory, 1 user can have 3 API tokens and 3 APP tokens in the same table.

I tried changing this line

```
    WHERE tokens.users_id = :user_id AND newest.id IS NULL
```

to

```
    WHERE tokens.users_id = :user_id AND newest.id IS NULL AND tokens.type = "API"
```

However it doesn't seem to work, infact it just returns no results at all... what am i doing wrong?

The fields in my tables are as follows:

TOKENS:
id
users_id
token
create_time
type
access_time

USERS:
id
email
password
active
verified
create_time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking about it just a little wrong.

The `WHERE` clause that you're modifying is on the `DELETE` statement, but you want to change what's being kept, not what's being deleted. The rows you want to keep are defined in the sub-query in the `FROM` clause. So that's where you want to put your new conditions. There might be a more elegant way to do this, but get three of each `type`, I just used a `UNION`.

```
DELETE tokens
FROM tokens
LEFT JOIN 
(
  (SELECT id
   FROM tokens
   WHERE users_id =users_id AND tokens.type = "API"
   ORDER BY access_time DESC 
   LIMIT 3)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT id
   FROM tokens
   WHERE users_id =users_id AND tokens.type = "APP"
   ORDER BY access_time DESC 
   LIMIT 3)
) AS newest 
    ON tokens.id = newest.id
WHERE 
  newest.id IS NULL;
```

Here's a working [Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/GWSNY52826).